# Adding AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore to an application using Azure AD SSO

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-identity

In my C# MVC web application, I am trying to use Microsoft's Azure AD as a sign-in gateway and nothing more, with AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore handling everything aside from the sign-in page. I have followed the [tutorials on the Microsoft Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-tutorial-01-register-application) for the basic Azure AD connection and had the login page appear properly, but after adding `builder.Services.AddIdentity` to Program.cs the Azure AD SSO has stopped appearing (I'm testing in anonymous windows so I know it isn't just my cache).

For clarity, my end goal is to have the Azure SSO be the first thing a user sees upon visiting my application, then after logging in they are sent to a controller action which finds and logs in the matching user in my EFCore Identity and returns the home page.

From the tutorials, I have:

```
// <ms_docref_add_default_controller_for_sign-in-out>
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
// </ms_docref_add_default_controller_for_sign-in-out>
```

When I add the following line, whether it is before or after the above line, the Azure AD SSO stops appearing.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<MyTUser, MyTRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Is there any way that I can have the Azure SSO appear before the EFCore Identity authorization?

Comment: Are you sure what you are trying to do is "supposed to work" or even "a good idea"? To me, what you are describing would require AAD B2C integration...

Comment: The intent is that the application will be used by the already-in-AzureAD users of a specific business, as the application is going to do recordkeeping on various apsects of that business. The reason we want Azure AD to just be the gateway is that it cannot handle role-based permissions in the way we want.

If I understand correctly, B2C is a means of generating new users in Azure from an application, which is the opposite of what we want.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it cannot handle role-based permissions in the way we want"? I have a strong gut feeling you are doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: My team lead wants the "roles" to be permissions to be for specific entities' CRUD actions, with a permission for foo-create, foo-read, bar-create, bar-update, and so on. The reasoning for this goal is to allow the client to define User Roles as compounds of those permissions, such that they can assign John Doe to UserRole on the frontend and the backend will apply each permission associated with UserRole to John Doe's user account. From what I've seen on the Azure AD site the roles there are meant for groups of permissions, so setting them up in this way would be a huge time sink. @julealgon

Comment: Granted, Azure AD is far outside my wheelhouse and the wheelhouses of my teammates, so I readily admit that despite my efforts to figure out how to do these connections properly I could have things completely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is clearly lack of familiarity on your part/your team's part. What you want to achieve is perfectly doable using either "app roles" (for daemon/application-to-application tokens), or "scopes" (for user tokens). I have multiple apps leveraging AAD in this manner with very fine-grained access controls like the one you want. All you need to do is define a scope for each, and then you add an attribute or policy to your controllers and actions pointing to those scopes.

Comment: For example, you could have a scope called 'Reservations.Read', which grants read-only permissions to one's own reservations (imagine a system where "Reservations" is an entity on the API). Then, you could have another scope called 'Reservations.Read.All' which grants that user access to _all_ reservations, regardless of who owns it. Then, you can have 'Reservations.ReadWrite', which give you write permissions, so on and so forth. You'd have these for each entity you want fine-grained control over. And in the controller, you annotate the actions accordingly.

Comment: The "roles" you are looking into right now is the more classic "group concept" as you said, but that's _not_ the mechanism you want at all. I recommend checking the "App Registrations" section of AAD, select your app, then under "App roles" you define the permissions for daemon access (Client Credentials flow), and in the "Expose an API" section you define the scopes for user access (which I assume is your intended flow here). The distinction between "app roles" and "scopes" can be a bit confusing, but I believe in your case there you only need to worry about scopes really.

Comment: @julealgon This information regarding the API is not helpful even if we ignore the fact that Microsoft charges extra for it. We want to avoid manually defining every single permission in Azure, but doing the API still has the issue of having to define them all and adds the issue of having to make an API call every time we want to check if a given user has a given permission. I appreciate that we agree on the fact that the Roles page in Azure is not what I want, but "The way to do roles in Azure is such and such" does not help when the end goal is not having them in Azure.

Comment: In that case, I believe you'll need to use Azure B2C to integrate your custom data/role management with AAD then. I do not think what you are trying to do right there is possible. I could be wrong, however. Good luck to you.